# JavaScript : Why does my password field not updating at all?

Tags: javascript

Why is my password field not updating at all? The password field is supposed to turn red after a user clicks out of the `id="password2"` input text field, yet it does not seem to want to work. Any thoughts?

This is my CSS

```
#denied {
    border: 1px ridge #272727;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 5px black;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 5px black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 97%;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: dota2fonts;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 5px #000000;
}
```

and this is my JavaScript

```
function initPage() {
    document.getElementById("￼password2").onblur = checkPassword;
}

function checkPassword() {
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
    if (password1 != password2) {
        password1.className = "denied";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's all I'm learning right now I'm my AJAX book and I'm 4 chapters in, so to me, this is AJAX. I guess I left out the request portion, but it wasn't necessary for the question. @Konza

Comment: Okay.You can edit your question.. "And this is my javascript" instead of "And this is my AJAX "..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable password1 holds the value of the field and not the element.
you should use `.classname` on the element

what you should do is

```
document.getElementById("password1").className = "denied";
```

but you are doing

```
document.getElementById("password1").value.className = "denied";
```

In your CSS it should be **.denied** not **#denied**

Comment: Thanks, just had one of those, maybe I should go to bed moments!